strong operator functional equvialent to weak operator continuous. A bit confused about a specific part in the proof.

I never really completely understood the first part of the proof for (iii) implies (i) even though I understood the rest of it. The thing that confuses me is that I know that a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous at a point $x \in X$ iff for every set(does not necessarily need to be open) $A$ in the neighborhood filter at $f(x)$ then there exists $B$ in the neighborhood filter of $x$ such that $f(B) \subset A$. In this case, I think the author is considering strong operator continuity at $0$ with the closed unit ball $\mathbf{B}$ in the complex field. Then there exists $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in \mathcal{H}$ and $\epsilon > 0$ such that $$\varphi \left( \bigcap^n \{T \in B(H): ||Tx_k|| < \epsilon\} \right) \subset \mathbf{B}$$But why is my $\epsilon = 1$ in this case?

Just divide $x_k$ by $\epsilon$.
